# Material UI input loses focus when opening menu

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to do input field which opens up menu when it's focused. Menu opens up just fine but input field loses focus and all custom styling when menu is visible.
Any ideas how to keep focus on input while menu is visible at same time?

Here is my handler:

```js
const [anchorElSearch, setAnchorElSearch] = React.useState(null);

const handleClickSearch = (event) => {
  setAnchorElSearch(event.currentTarget);
};
```

Here is my Input field and Menu components:

```js
<Input
  className={classes.searchInput}
  classes={{ focused: classes.searchInputFocused }}
  aria-controls="searchMenu"
  aria-haspopup="true"
  onClick={handleClickSearch}
/>
<Menu
  id="searchMenu"
  anchorEl={anchorElSearch}
  keepMounted
  open={Boolean(anchorElSearch)}
>
  <MenuItem onClick={handleCloseSearch}>Works</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Do you just care about the styles persisting when the menu is open or is it really about persisting the focus? The latter would arguably be considered bad UX, as you would expect users to interact with a menu they just opened.

Comment: I'm trying to do same kind of search bar as github has

Answer (score 4):

I would forego the `Menu` component and implement something like this:

```js
const { ClickAwayListener, Input, MenuList, MenuItem, makeStyles } = MaterialUI

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  searchInputFocused: {
    border: "1px solid hotpink"
  }
});

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickSearch = () => {
    setOpen((prev) => !prev);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
      <div>
        <Input
          classes={{ focused: classes.searchInputFocused }}
          onClick={handleClickSearch}
        />
        {open ? (
          <MenuList
            onClick={handleClose}
            style={{ background: "#eeeeee" }}
          >
            <MenuItem>Item 1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>Item 2</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>Item 3</MenuItem>
          </MenuList>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </ClickAwayListener>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@latest/babel.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Tried that but for some reason whole input field disappearing when opening menulist. Did that exactly same way as you did so problem is somewhere else.. Trying to figure out whats going on

Comment: Can't get it work. I tried to comment out all of styling but clicking input it opens up menulist but hides input itself..

Comment: Give me a codesandbox and I'll take a look. Try to remove code that you are confident is not related, please.

Comment: Alternatively, just start out with my code and add yours step by step. That should let you know what causes problems.

Comment: I think solution for this might be too complicated so I solved the problem opening menu component top of the input bar and giving a little styling for it. Realized that github probably does it same way, if you look close you can see inputs blue outline underneath the menu.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue (with a TextArea component from MUIv5 losing focus when the Menu component is open) and i solved it by adding the MUI prop `disableAutoFocus` to the Menu! works like a charm in case someone else is trying to achieve the same effect.

```
<TextArea
  onClick={(e) => openMenu(e)}
  value={searchText}
  onChange={onChange}
  sx={{my styling}}
/>
<Menu
  id="searchMenu"
  anchorEl={anchorElSearch}
  open={Boolean(anchorElSearch)}
  disableAutoFocus
>
  // Menu content
</Menu>
```

Comment: Simple and working. Thanks!